# Vue.js initialization in Django

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

I'm using django and Vue.js to build some panels. I'm joining Vue.js to Django in test mode and I have this issue:

"dist" vue.js folder is served using the django.contrib.staticfiles module, and when I ask for index.html anything is downloaded with no issues.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/wwwdocs/index.html
```

However, when vue.js start and download other stuff it fails because it tries to download data from another path:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/appb17d7483.css
http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.a322f2ed.js
```

It removed the "wwwdocs" from the url.
Is here a fast solution to solve this and have vue.js downloading the modules from the same path it was downloaded ( /wwwdocs ) ?

Comment: maybe you don't maked the integration well. Read this https://medium.com/@williamgnlee/simple-integrated-django-vue-js-web-application-configured-for-heroku-deployment-c4bd2b37aa70

Comment: Great article to read! Meanwhile I solved the issue using Apache as proxy server.

Comment: can you post here your solution @ozw1z5rd ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EaBt1xHJ